# cannot read property 'client_secret' of undefined

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I have tried to create a sample program using Node.js, following instructions from https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/v1/quickstart/nodejs

I throws an error saying **cannot read property 'client_secret' of undefined** when trying to run it.

Looking for your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;`
In this line credentials is pointing to `client_secret.json` so the first key has to be "installed". In my case the key was "web" and that was causing the error. I just renamed the key "web" to "installed".

Answer (score 10):

Since there is no key named "installed", it's parsing it to be `undefined`.

In `credentials.json` change the key "web" to "installed". Probably the docs need to change from Google's side.

### Before

[image]

### After

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

It seems you have missed [Step 1: Turn on the Google Apps Activity API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/v1/quickstart/nodejs).

After creating the Credentials:

> f. Click the file_download (Download JSON) button to the right of the
>   client ID.
>
> g. Move this file to your working directory and rename it
>   client_secret.json. Put it in your project folder.

Comment: I didn't miss first step.
I have downloaded the JSON file renamed it to client_secret and placed it in my working directory.

Comment: when you renamed it to client_secret, did you keep the file extension .json? So the file must be client_secret.json  And did you place it in your project folder?

Comment: Yes the file name is client_secret.json
I didn't forget extension .json. I have also placed the file in project folder.

Comment: Did you place it in your project folder?

Comment: Yes I have placed it in my project folder.

Comment: What version of NodeJS are you using?

Comment: version of NodeJS I use is v4.4.7

Comment: This should be working now. Did a quick run of this and it works for me. Is your oauth clientID of type 'Other' ?

Comment: Oh.. May be that's where I missed it. Thanks for your time. Will look into it.

Comment: @noogui The "other" part was what messed me up. Thanks for posting. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Your `client_secret.json` file needs to have the line below:

```
"redirect_uris": ["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", "http://localhost"]
```

instead of the lines like below:

```
"javascript_origins":
    [
      "http://localhost:8080",
      "http://localhost:1453",
      "http://127.0.0.1:1453",
      "http://localhost"
    ]
```

Also you may want to change chain head in `client_secret.json` from `web` to `installed`, or vise versa.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, but I had the wrong type of credentials file. I initially used "Web Server (Nodejs)...", and it had the "web" heading instead of the "installed", but when I did it again, and selected "Windows UI (cmd line)", I got the file with the correct format.

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting the application type "Other".
Select the "Help me choose" option and there you can chose other application type.
That way your client_secret.json will have the variable named "installed".

Answer (score 0):

The recent version of Google Drive API will have a **Desktop client** option while creating OAuth API Key. Do select that, it will have all required information to access Google drive from Script.