# Setting up Google Drive API on NodeJS using a service account

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I'm trying to connect to the Google Drive API with a NodeJS server using a service account. The goal is for the server to be able to authenticate as the service account, retrieve relevant files from a drive, and send them back to the user, without the user needing to log in to Google directly. This would allow me to control file access through my web app instead of having to manually share and unshare files through Drive. From my understanding of the Google Drive API, this should all be possible. The problem is that I can't even figure out how to authenticate my server. The server runs on an AWS EC2 instance. To clarify, I **do not** want the user to have to authenticate using the frontend interface.

I've followed the [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/nodejs) and set up a service account & key as instructed [here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#service-account), but upon creating the key as instructed in the second link, it doesn't look like I have the correct `credentials.json` file. The JSON file I get after generating a key on the Google Developer Console has the following object keys (values intentionally removed):

- `type`, `project_id`, `private_key_id`, `private_key`, `client_email`, `client_id`, `auth_uri`, `token_uri`, `auth_provider_x509_cert_url`, `client_x509_cert_url`

[image]

The quickstart guide suggests that this file should contain `client_secret` and `redirect_uris` within some `installed` object (`const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;`):

[image: screenshot]

Attempting to run this `index.js` quickstart file causes an error to be thrown, since `installed` does not exist within `credentials.json`. Where can I generate the necessary credentials file? Or am I on the wrong track completely?

Posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487479/cannot-read-property-client-secret-of-undefined) reference a similar issue on an older version of the quickstart documentation, but the solutions here don't help since there isn't a `client_secret` key in my credentials file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I saw the showing keys of your `credentials.json` file, I understood that the file is the credential file of the service account. If my understanding is correct, when I saw your showing script, it seems that the script is for OAuth2. In this case, this script cannot be used for the service account. I thought that this is the reason for your current issue.

In order to use Drive API using the service account, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set `credentialFilename` of the service account. In this case, please include the path.

```js
const { google } = require("googleapis");

const credentialFilename = "credentials.json";
const scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly"];

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({keyFile: credentialFilename, scopes: scopes});
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });

// This is a simple sample script for retrieving the file list.
drive.files.list(
  {
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log("The API returned an error: " + err);
    const files = res.data.files;
    console.log(files);
  }
);
```

- When this script is run, as a sample script, the file list is retrieved from the Google Drive of the service account. So, please modify this for your actual situation.
- This sample script uses `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly` as the scope. Please modify this for your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [Google APIs Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)

Comment: Ah. I think I briefly attempted to work with something similar to this earlier, but kept getting the following error: `google.auth.GoogleAuth is not a constructor`. At the time, I thought that I was just using the wrong script, but it looks like the error was caused by an outdated version of googleapis. The docs I read somewhere said to use googleapis@39. Updating to the latest version seems to do the trick. Thank you! 4 hours of reading various docs and you gave me an answer within minutes. Much appreciated!

Comment: For anybody who comes across this in the future, I used the script @Tanaike provided and just removed the line `const creds = ...` as it was giving me a "module not found" error.

Comment: @Riley Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `const creds = ...`, I forgot to remove this line. I apologize for this. Also, I updated my answer. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else spent too much time working out how to authenticate with a service account, this is how I got uploading a file to work:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const drive = google.drive('v3');
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  credentials: {
    client_email: process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL,
    client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    private_key: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
  },
  scopes: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  ],
});

async function handler(req, res) {
  const authClient = await auth.getClient();
  google.options({ auth: authClient });

  try {
    await drive.files.create({
      requestBody: {
        name: 'Test',
        mimeType: 'text/plain',
        parents: [FOLDER_ID], // make sure to share the folder with your service account
      },
      media: {
        mimeType: 'text/plain',
        body: 'Hello World',
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: `Error adding row. ${error.message}` });
  }

  return res.status(201).json({ message: 'Done' });
}

export default handler;
```