# How to download a spreadsheet from google drive using a service account and typescript/node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to download all the spreadsheets contained in a folder using a service account.
I cannot find a solution, I hope someone could help me.

I authenticate and I get successfully `drive.files.list` but then I can't download files.
This is my code

```
import { google } from "googleapis";
import { privatekey } from "./privatekey";
import { createWriteStream, writeFileSync } from "fs";

let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(privatekey.client_email, undefined, privatekey.private_key, [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
]);
//authenticate request
jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully connected");
    }
});

const folder_id = FOLDER_ID
let drive = google.drive("v3");
drive.files.list(
    {
        auth: jwtClient,
        q: `'${folder_id}' in parents and trashed=false`,
    },
    function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("The API returned an error: " + err);
            return;
        }
        var files = response?.data.files;
        if (files?.length == 0) return;
        files?.forEach(async (file) => {
            let fileId = file.id;
            fileId == null ? (fileId = undefined) : (fileId = fileId);
            //writeFileSync(`./cartella/${file.id}.xlsx`, "");
            prova(jwtClient, fileId, file.mimeType);
            //await getFileFromStream(jwtClient, fileId, file.mimeType);
        });
    }
);

function getFileFromStream(auth: any, fileId: any, mimeType: any) {
    const destPath = `./cartella/${fileId}.xls`;
    const dest = createWriteStream(destPath);
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
        drive.files.get({
            fileId: fileId,
            alt: "media",
        }),
            (err: any, res: any): void => {
                res.data
                    .on("end", () => {
                        console.log("Done");
                    })
                    .on("error", (error: any) => {
                        console.log("Error during download", error);
                    })
                    .pipe(dest);
            };
    });
}
function prova(auth: any, fileId: any, mimeType: any) {
    const destPath = `./cartella/${fileId}.xls`;
    const dest = createWriteStream(destPath);

    const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
    drive.files.export({ fileId: fileId, mimeType: mimeType },{responseType: "stream"}, (err: any, res: any) => {
  if (err) {
    //   handle error
          console.log("error: ",err)
  } else {
          if (res == null) return
    res.data
      .on("end", function () {
        console.log("Done");
      })
      .on("error", function (err: any) {
        console.log("Error during download", err);
      })
      .pipe(dest);
  }})
}
```

First of all I added the service account to the editors of the folder in google drive

The function `getFileFromStream` returns a big error, but I think that the most interesting thing is this one

```
domain: 'global',
reason: 'fileNotDownloadable',       
message: 'Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Docs Editors files.',            locationType: 'parameter',    
   location: 'alt'     }   ]
```

So I tried to use `drive.files.export`, but the response is

```
status: 400,  
   statusText: 'Bad Request',   
   request: {       
       responseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/file_id/export?mimeType=application%2Fvnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'   
  }
```

I also tried a different authentication method like the one proposed here:
[Setting up Google Drive API on NodeJS using a service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71744751/setting-up-google-drive-api-on-nodejs-using-a-service-account)
but it still does't work

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About your error message of `Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Docs Editors files.`, in this case, it is considered that you are trying to download Google Docs file (Document, Spreadsheet, Slides and so on). In this case, it is required to use the export method. For your current issue, I thought that this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64337805 In this answer, the export method and the get method are used by depending on the mimeType.

Comment: From your posted answer, I flagged your question as a duplicated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found here:
[How to download dynamic files from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64337805/how-to-download-dynamic-files-from-google-drive)

Thank you [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

The following method will download files that are not Google Drive [mime types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/mime-types).  You only need to use export if it is a Google Drive [mime types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/mime-types) and you need to covert it when its download for example a Google sheet converted to an excel file, or a Google docs file converted to a Microsoft word file.

```
def download_file(service, file_id):

    try:

        # Call the Drive v3 API
        # Get file name, so we can save it as the same with the same name.
        file = service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()
        file_name = file.get("name")
        print(f'File name is: {file_name}')

        # Call the Drive v3 API
        # get the file media data
        request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)

        fh = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            print("Download %d%%" % int(status.progress() * 100))

        # The file has been downloaded into RAM, now save it in a file
        fh.seek(0)
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(fh, f, length=131072)

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```